# How to refresh the fragment inside viewpager dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have one ViewPager(mainViewPager) inside my MainActivity which renders from a fragment that contains another ViewPager(imageViewPager) and a TextView. Now The imageViewPager renders from another fragment that contains ImageView and a button. I've set onClick listener on this ImageView that turns in fullscreen view of the image with a button beneath.Now onClick of this buttton I want to return to my MainActivity with the condition to be on the same page from which I entered and with the same image which I viewed last in fullscreen.I am able to get the same page but the image always starts from 0.

Basically my hierarchy is like:

```
MainActivity
   --mainViewPager-->TaskFragment
                        --imageViewPager-->ImageFragment(contains only ImageView
                        --TextView(set text returned from MainActivity)
```

My Code:
**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private CustomPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
        private int changedPosition;

        private String[] vehicles = new String[]{"Audi Q7", "Honda Accord", "Hyundai i20", "Maruti Suzuki Swift", "Mahindra XUV 500",
                "Swift Dzire", "Honda City", "Honda Civic", "Mercedez Benz", "Rolls Royce", "Ferrari"};

        private String[][] vehicle_info = new String[][]{
                {"http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/2010_abt_audi_q7_3_tdi_3-wide.jpg",
                        "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/2010_mtm_audi_s5_cabrio_michelle_edition-wide.jpg",
                        "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/2009_audi_tts_coupe_car-wide.jpg"},
                {"http://automobiles.honda.com/images/2015/accord-sedan/exterior-gallery/2015-honda-accord-sedan-sport-exterior-side1.jpg",
                        "http://www.carprousa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/HondaInterior-e1421978263126.jpg",
                        "http://www.carprousa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/HondaInterior2-e1421978365916.jpg"},
                ...........
};


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.mainViewPager);
            mPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), vehicles, vehicle_info);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 0) {

                changedPosition = data.getIntExtra("CHANGED_POSITION", 0);
                Log.i("POSITION 3:"," "+changedPosition);

                TaskFragment fragment = new TaskFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("IMAGE_POSITION", changedPosition);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            }
        }

    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**CustomPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    private String[] vehicles,selected_vehicle_info;
    private String[][] vehicle_info;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager,String[] vehicles,String[][] vehicle_info){
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
        this.vehicle_info = vehicle_info;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        selected_vehicle_info = vehicle_info[position];

        TaskFragment taskFragment = new TaskFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("ITEM",vehicles[position]);
        bundle.putStringArray("ITEM_INFO",selected_vehicle_info);
        taskFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return taskFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return vehicles.length;
    }
}
```

**TaskFragment.java**

```
public class TaskFragment extends Fragment {

    private String vehicle;
    private String[] vehicle_info;
    private ViewPager imageViewPager;
    private ImagePagerAdapter imagePagerAdapter;
    private int changedImagePosition;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        vehicle = getArguments().getString("ITEM");
        vehicle_info = getArguments().getStringArray("ITEM_INFO");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_task_fragment,container,false);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        messageTextView.setText(vehicle);

        imageViewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPager);

        imagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getActivity(), vehicle_info);
        imagePagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        imageViewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);
        imageViewPager.setCurrentItem(changedImagePosition);

        return view;
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private Activity activity;
        private String[] vehicle_info;

        public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity activity,String[] vehicle_info){
            this.activity = activity;
            this.vehicle_info = vehicle_info;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_image_fragment,container,false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            Picasso.with(getContext()).load(vehicle_info[position]).into(imageView);

            if(imageView.getParent()!=null)
                ((ViewGroup)imageView.getParent()).removeView(imageView);

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ImageInFullScreen.class);
                    intent.putExtra("IMAGES_URL", vehicle_info);
                    intent.putExtra("IMAGE_POSITION", position);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            });
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return vehicle_info.length;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }
    }

}
```

**ImageInFullScreen.java**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("CHANGED_POSITION",changedImgPosition);
                setResult(0,intent);}});
```

//and the same adapter n all.

Comment: pls help me with this guys. I am a newbie.:_) Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question, the problem was that somehow my setCurrentItem() wasn't working inside TaskFragment's onCreateView(), so I've moved it to the Run method of Runnable interface's postAtTime()nd then it worked perfectly.

Here's my edited code.

**MainActivity.java**`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 0) {

            claim_id = vehicleDetailsArrayList.get(changedPage).getClaimId();

            //Retrieve value of position of last viewed image, before clicking the button
            changedPosition = data.getIntExtra("CHANGED_POSITION", 0);
            Log.i("POSITION 3:"," "+changedPosition);

            if(changedPage > -1 && changedPage < vehicleDetailsArrayList.size()) {
                addUpdateImagePositionInList(claim_id, changedPosition);
            }

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mViewPager.getAdapter() != null) {
                        mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }, 0);
        }
    }

    public void addUpdateImagePositionInList(int claimId, int position){
        for (int imageLength = 0; imageLength < imagePositionArrayList.size(); imageLength++)
        {
            if (claimId == (imagePositionArrayList.get(imageLength).getClaim_id()))
            {
                imagePositionArrayList.get(imageLength).setImagePosition(position);
                return;
            }
        }
        imagePositionArrayList.add(new ImagePosition(claimId, position));
    }

    public int getChangedImagePosition(int claimId){
        for (int imageLength = 0; imageLength < imagePositionArrayList.size(); imageLength++)
        {
            if (claimId == (imagePositionArrayList.get(imageLength).getClaim_id()))
            {
                Log.i("POSITION123 ","  ::"+ imagePositionArrayList.get(imageLength).getImagePosition() );
                return imagePositionArrayList.get(imageLength).getImagePosition();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
`
```

**TaskFragment.java**`

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        id = getArguments().getInt("ID");
        vehicle = getArguments().getString("ITEM");
        vehicle_info = getArguments().getStringArray("ITEM_INFO");

        changedImagePosition = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getChangedImagePosition(id);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_fragment,container,false);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        messageTextView.setText(vehicle);

        imageViewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPager);
        imagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(getActivity(), vehicle_info);
        imageViewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);

        /*The below code doesn't work
        if (imageViewPager.getCurrentItem() != changedImagePosition) {

            Log.i("POSITION current", ":" + imageViewPager.getCurrentItem());
            Log.i("POSITION changed", " :"+ changedImagePosition);

            setCurrentItem = true;
            imageViewPager.setCurrentItem(changedImagePosition, false);
            Log.i("POSITION getCurrent", " :" + imageViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        }
        */


        new Handler().postAtTime(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (imageViewPager.getAdapter() != null) {
                    imageViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                    imageViewPager.setCurrentItem(changedImagePosition);
                }
            }
        },0);

        return view;
    }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

where ever you want to refresh the view put the following code

```
this.page_position = 0;
imagePagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and in your ImagePagerAdapter override the following function -

```
@Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
```

POSITION_NONE means whenever notifyDataSetChanged is called, adapter will create fresh views rather than using the same views.

This should work in our case.

Comment: I've already tried it,but this didn't worked. Instead of loading the imageviewpager with last viewed image in fullscreen, it loads it with the image on which we clicked and entered into fullscreen. thanks though.@Android_developer